# Peach Tree Sun Exposure

Tags: trees, peaches

Recently transplanted a small Peach Tree from indoor to outdoor about a week ago.  Tree seems like it was doing fine until today, today is the first day the temperature has reached above 85 and it is extremely bright and sunny(Delaware). A few of the very top leaves have learned a much lighter color, has a whiteish tint to it. Should I put a cover it to try and limit sun exposure?

Comment: Did you harden it off before finally planting it out?

Comment: I'm guessing no since I do not know what that means

Comment: I did some research and discovered when it means to Harden it off. I did not do that.  Does this mean the tree is loss cause now?

Comment: Okay I got the tree under shade cloth about 9am this morning.  The ground is still moist ( When I was watering it I just had the hose on a trickle) from my watering yesterday and since I was over watering it yesterday I'm going to hold off on that for now.  Thank you Bamboo and Stormy for all your help so far!
1. https://ibb.co/hdk3G7     2. https://ibb.co/ntLEOn     3. https://ibb.co/nR2kES     4. https://ibb.co/bDeRM7

I have my last final exam of the semester this evening that I am going to continue to study for but I will check back once that is over.  Thank you again!

Answer (score 2):

You've confirmed you did not harden off your peach tree before transferring it outdoors; there's nothing to be done about that now it's planted. It doesn't mean its going to die, just that it will likely suffer from any cool temperatures as well as suffering some sunburn. That just means the leaves you've got now might not look very good, or may even drop off - but the plant should acclimatize and put out new growth, provided you keep it well watered.

Comment: I have been watering it but trying not to over water it.  I've been putting on a very slow stream on it for one hour then off an hour and have been alternating this throughout the day.
Pictures of the tree take moments ago.
https://ibb.co/hdk3G7
https://ibb.co/ntLEOn

Comment: That's probably too much watering! A hose trickling at the base for an hour or so once a day should be sufficient, depending on how hot and dry the weather is.

Answer (score 1):

Not necessarily, E.B. Keep that plant watered and I would get some shade cloth to cover it for a while. Acclimatization or hardening off takes weeks to ensure the plant's leaves epidermis gets thicker. Otherwise, your plant will get sunburn. Your plant has gotten sunburn and is in a bit of shock. Find some shade cloth; it is a black plastic fabric that comes in different weaves to protect by blocking sunlight in various percentages. I would get a 30 % block and lightly cover your plant for a few weeks. I would also give it a balanced fertilizer if you have not already done so.

Your tree has a chance but covering it to reduce the amount of heat and IR from the sun will help an awful lot!  How did you plant this tree?  Was it in a pot?  Or B&B in a pot?  Balled and Burlapped and set in a pot.  How did you dig the hole, did you do anything to amend the soil?  I hope not?

Send a picture, please.  Go to your nursery and ask for shade cloth.  Use a few upright bamboo stakes to hold the fabric away from the tree or at least reduce the weight of fabric on the tree. Keep it watered, deeply..what kind of soil do you have?  You might need to insert pvc plastic pipe with holes drilled into the soil near the root ball to ensure the water is getting to the roots.

Comment: This was my first time ever attempting to grow anything, I just keep some peach stones from last summer in a fridge until about last December, got one to sprout and threw it in a pot that was mixed with about a 50/50 mix of local earth and fruit tree potting mix.  Usually this time of the year, we don't have anymore temperatures that drop below freezing so I planted it 50/50 local and fruit tree soil. I'm not sure what you are asking how I dug the hole... with a shovel?, Filled it with water first then stuck it in the ground.

Comment: Link to two pictures of the tree I took just moments ago.
https://ibb.co/hdk3G7
https://ibb.co/ntLEOn

Comment: Yeah, I am sure you used a shovel.  Main thing is that the stem of your tree has no soil or mulch or anything on it holding in moisture.  Just the root ball should be under the soil.  I always ask this because most people don't know this and this will eventually kill a tree.  The root ball should sit on undisturbed soil.  If the disturbed soil beneath

Comment: Only found one picture.  Not bad, definitely not that happy but your tree should survive.  I would get that shade cloth or even use Reemay...Row Cloth...it is white, it will reflect IR and it is still a loose weave to allow air flow...I'd water the soil not over the Reemay.  If you are able to dig down in the soil, can you see how deep the moisture goes?  I think you are overwatering...filled the hole with water was the best thing you needed to do before planting.  It is planted and I think it will pull out of its...little shock.

Comment: If you have 85 degree weather for the next few days I would definitely cover this plant or try to shade it from the sun.  You grew this from a seed?  Ought to be interesting...this is your first project and by golly we need to help you succeed.  You may never get peaches...there are orchardists on this site that will definitely give you some ideas.  Do you have indoor plants?  A patio?  Landscape? Any one who saves peach pits and attempts to grow them has a gardener inside needing to be let out!  In the future, no garden soil in pots.  Just potting soil.  I would go with your intuition, shade.

Comment: Thank you for the info. I am going to get a shade cloth first thing in the morning. I should've done more research, I just took some advice from my mother who started a persimmon tree from seeds 3-4 years ago and it is going strong. Last year it actually bore fruit.  I planted this peach tree about 20feet away from that Persimmon tree.

Comment: No, I do not have indoor/patio plants and have never done any landscaping. Not sure exactly why I decided to try and grow a peach tree from a seed. Thank you again for the info.